# VSCode: Set Terminal Output Line / Column Length

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I set the terminal output to show all the columns in a single output?

Consider this example:

[image: output with 3 columns]

This gives me a very generous output of 2-3 columns at a time!

Following [this guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_61#_fixed-dimensions), executing this command in the VS Code Command Palette: `Terminal: Set Fixed Dimensions`

And I enter `1000` for columns, and nothing for rows, I get the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've noticed that this setting behaves a little weird/buggy.  When I first set it, once the cursor reached the edge of the terminal, the cursor returned back to the beginning on the same line and began to overwrite my text.

I killed the terminal and opened a new one, set the column dimensions again, and now it seems to work.

[image: gif showing 1000 columns scrolling]

So I would try the following:

1. Kill any terminal processes
2. Set the dimensions again
3. Reset Visual Studio Code
4. Try steps 1 and 2 again

I tried this using Bash and Powershell and both worked. I'm unsure if all shells are supported or not.

Comment: hmm perhaps this only works for bash and not Python

Comment: @JohnStud what is the shell you are using?

Comment: Its outputting to `Python - Desktop` but I am using WSL:Ubuntu on my VSCode.